# Jitter almost duplicate rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with coordinate values:

```
data = [
    ['c', 2.2, 3.4],
    ['b', 2.2, 3.41],
    ['a', 1.05, 1.0],
    ['a', 2.2, 3.39],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['T', 'x', 'y'])
```

```
    T     x     y
0   c  2.20  3.40
1   b  2.20  3.41
2   a  1.05  1.00
3   a  2.20  3.39
```

How can I jitter values of rows that have x,y coordinates too close to each other? For example if distance between their x,y coordinates is less than `0.1` I want to jitter by X axis so it becomes more than `0.1`. Something like this:

```
    T     x     y
0   c  2.18  3.40
1   b  2.20  3.42
2   a  1.05  1.00
3   a  2.22  3.39
```

Comment: I have no knowledge of `jitter` but to my understanding, if you are working with x and y coordinates, then using an extra column as `area` would work (if they are too close it's because the have the same area I guess) therefore you can create an extra column as flag for those that are too close, and then run it a loop to correct the x and y coordinates, together with some constraints maybe. For instace add a random value to x, but that random value cannot be larger than 5, and if the condition is still not met, add the random value to y, and so on... Would this work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `scipy`'s `pdist`

Please look up each of these functions to learn what they do.

- [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html)
- [`numpy.triu_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html)
- [`numpy.logical_or.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html)
- [`numpy.ufunc.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html)

This isn't easy but it works well

---

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

p = pdist(df[['x', 'y']])                 # Get (n ** 2 - n) / 2 distances
n = len(df)
i, j = np.triu_indices(n, 1)              # indices of the upper triangle
                                          # of a distance matrix.  Coincides
                                          # with calculations from pdist

too_close = np.zeros(n, bool)             # Initialize a mask for what's close
np.logical_or.at(too_close, i, p <= .1)   # logically accumulate if any thing
                                          # is too close per row
                                          # Note: this will not dupe by the
                                          # nature of grabbing the upper triangle

shape = (too_close.sum(), 2)
rng = np.random.rand(*shape) * .2         # The jittering
df.loc[too_close, ['x', 'y']] += rng

df.plot.scatter('x', 'y')
```

[image]

---

#### Side Note

This will "jitter" the first things that are too close while leaving the later ones alone.  If you want it the other way, use `j` in the `np.logical_or.at` calculation.  `np.logical_or.at(too_close, j, p <= .1)`

With `i`

```
   T         x         y
0  c  2.247206  3.460875  # <- Changed
1  b  2.254998  3.413094  # <- Changed
2  a  1.050000  1.000000
3  a  2.200000  3.390000  # <- Not Changed
```

With `j`

```
   T         x         y
0  c  2.200000  3.400000  # <- Not Changed
1  b  2.277618  3.500489  # <- Changed
2  a  1.050000  1.000000
3  a  2.237443  3.427577  # <- Changed
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It took some time to understand. I learned a lot. Please look at mine. What do you think of it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
def jitter_x(grp):
    if len(grp) > 1:
        min_x = grp['x'].min()
        # X coordinates are evenly spaced starting from their minimum
        jittered_x = np.linspace(0, len(grp) * 0.1, num=len(grp), endpoint=False) + min_x
        grp.loc[:, 'x'] = jittered_x
    return grp


# group by rounded coordinates
def by_coords(idx):
    return '{:0.1f},{:0.1f}'.format(df.loc[idx, 'x'], df.loc[idx, 'y'])



df = df.groupby(by_coords).apply(jitter_x)
```